# Having trouble adding wxListBox to frame

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to add a wxListBox to my frame, but I am having some difficulty.

This is my sample code

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(750,690), style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|
              wx.CAPTION|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

    splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
    panel1 = panel1(splitter)
    panel2 = wx.Panel(splitter,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    splitter.SplitHorizontally(panel1,panel2,470)
    listBox = wx.ListBox(splitter, -1, (20, 20), (80, 120), 0, wx.LB_SINGLE)
```

I am getting this error,
      *controls*.ListBox_swiginit(self,*controls*.new_ListBox(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: Sequence of strings expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
listBox = wx.ListBox(splitter, -1, (20, 20), (80, 120), 0, wx.LB_SINGLE)
```

should be something like:

```
listBox = wx.ListBox(panel1, -1, (20, 20), (80, 120), [a list of choices], wx.LB_SINGLE)
```

Instead of parenting it to the splitter use one of your panels or if you want it outside the splitter then use 'self' which is your frame here.

You are hardcoding sizes and positions, instead I suggest to look into using sizers.  see e.g. http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingSizers or do a google search.

Comment: How do you add the listbox to the frame?

Comment: The parent doesn't explain the error, it's perfectly possible to create the listbox directly as the child of the splitter if this is what you want -- except that one of the panels would become unnecessary then. The error is solely due to using `0` instead of `[...]` for the strings.